# Is it legal to partially specialise variadic template inner class with args from variadic template of an outer class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... Ts>
struct outer {
   template <class... ITs>
   struct inner {
      static constexpr bool value = false;
   };

   template <class... ITs>
   struct inner<Ts..., ITs...> {   
      static constexpr bool value = true;
   };
};

int main() {
   std::cout << outer<int, float, double>::inner<int, float, double, int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

The code compiles with clang++ but not with g++ where it produces an error:

> temp3.cc:11:11: error: parameter pack argument ‘Ts ...’ must be at the
>   end of the template argument list
>
> ```
> struct inner<Ts..., ITs...> {
>        ^
> ```

As I've already established [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766902/is-it-legit-to-specialize-variadic-template-class-inside-other-template-class) partial specialisation of the inner class should be legit.

**Edit:**
For completeness it is worth adding that clang for the above code warns that he might have a problem with deducing ITs parameters yet doing it without any problems...

Comment: I don't know the rules exactly, but when I get an error with a dependent type, adding `typename` or `template` before it sometimes helps. Try `struct inner<typename Ts...`.

Comment: after adding `typename` I get `temp3.cc:11:39: error: template argument 1 is invalid`

Comment: It is to be noted that the requested scenario can still be implemented with some additional template metaprogramming... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c6c643c8ff5809e (yes, I know that was not the question but the challenge of implementing it was unavoidable...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a gcc bug. This is a perfectly valid partial specialization:

```
template <class... ITs>
struct inner<Ts..., ITs...> {   
   static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

Deduced template parameter packs must be last, and `ITs...` satisfies that. But `Ts...` isn't a pack that needs to be deduced here, it's just a specific parameter pack.

Furthermore, gcc compiles several equivalent formulations:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct X {
    template <class... Us>
    static void foo(Ts..., Us...) { }
};

int main() {
   X<int>::foo(1, 'c');
}
```

and:

```
template <class... Us>
struct A { };

template <class... Ts>
struct X {
    template <class... Us>
    static void foo(A<Ts..., Us...>) { }
};

int main() {
   X<int>::foo(A<int, char>{});
}
```

These are equivalently well-formed to your original example.

Comment: I suspected that but wasn't sure if isn't there some special rule for the context of specialization inside a template class. Is it a known bug?

Comment: I do agree that it makes sense for the partial specialization to be valid, but I'm not sure that the Standard as written allows it. [14.5.5p8.5] says *If an argument is a pack expansion (14.5.3), it shall be the last argument in the template argument list*. It's a specific requirement on partial specializations, so it doesn't apply to your examples. This looks more like a Standard issue than a compiler bug to me.

Comment: You should submit bug report to `gcc`. Have you done?

Comment: @bogdan I don't think `Ts...` counts as a pack expansion - it will have already been expanded by the time we consider the partial specialization, no?

Comment: I've seen [the discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/pMaEyvcC9Y8), but I'm not convinced. I'll reply to that thread.

Comment: I don't think we're going to get any more information out of that thread. My conclusion based on the discussion is that the intent is for this to work but a strict interpretation of the wording disallows it. GCC, MSVC and EDG take the wording literally, while Clang implements the intended behaviour; it's hard to place the blame on any of them without clarifying the wording first. I heard there's an ISO rule specifying that the OP on std-discussion is also the one who sends the issue report :-).

Answer (score 1):

Riding on W.F.'s answer, still keeping the same main as in the original question:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... Ts>
struct pack { };

template <class... Ts>
class outer {
   template <class IT>
   struct _inner {
      static constexpr bool value = false;
   };

   template <class... ITs>
   struct _inner<pack<Ts..., ITs...>> {
      static constexpr bool value = true;
   };
public:
   template <class... ITs>
   struct inner {
      static constexpr bool value = _inner<pack<ITs...>>::value;
   };    
};

int main() {
   std::cout << outer<int, float, double>::inner<int, float, double, int>::value
             << std::endl;
}
```

It still produces a warning in clang, because the specialized version of _inner couldn't deduce ITs... apart from the list of Ts..., ITs... (in `struct _inner<pack<Ts..., ITs...>>`) -- however the code do not require ITs to be deduced separately from the list of Ts..., ITs..., so this should be ok.

In g++ it compiles without a warning.

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae3b21dd847450b2

(For a solution without a warning also in clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c6c643c8ff5809e).

Answer (score 0):

Possible simple yet effective workaround inspired on Barry's answer:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... Ts>
struct pack { };

template <class... Ts>
struct outer {
   template <class IT>
   struct inner {
      static constexpr bool value = false;
   };

   template <class... ITs>
   struct inner<pack<Ts..., ITs...>> {   
      static constexpr bool value = true;
   };
};

int main() {
   std::cout << outer<int, float, double>::inner<pack<int, float, double, int>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

(It still produces the warning in clang though)