# Which is the more specialized template function? clang and g++ differ on that

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, overloading

While playing with variadic templates, following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767558/is-it-legal-to-partially-specialise-variadic-template-inner-class-with-args-from/37916494#37916494) (note: it is not mandatory to go there for following this question), I came to a different behavior of clang (3.8) and g++ (6.1) for the following template overloaded functions:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct pack { };

template <class a, class b>
constexpr bool starts_with(a, b) {
    return false;
}

template <template <typename...> class PACK_A,
          template <typename...> class PACK_B, typename... Ts1, typename... Ts2>
constexpr bool starts_with(PACK_A<Ts1..., Ts2...>, PACK_B<Ts1...>) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
   std::cout << std::boolalpha;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(),
                            pack<float, int, double>())        << std::endl;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(),
                            pack<int, float, double, int>())   << std::endl;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(),
                            pack<int, float, int>())           << std::endl;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(),
                            pack<int, float, double>())        << std::endl;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(),
                            pack<int>())                       << std::endl;
}
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b62fa93ea88fa25b

### Output

```
|---|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| # |starts_with(a, b)                  | expected    | clang (3.8) | g++ (6.1)   |
|---|-----------------------------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1 |a: pack<int, float, double>()      |  false      |  false      |  false      |
|   |b: pack<float, int, double>()      |             |             |             |
|---|-----------------------------------|-------------|-------------|--------- ---|
| 2 |a: pack<int, float, double>()      |  false      |  false      |  false      |
|   |b: pack<int, float, double, int>() |             |             |             |
|---|-----------------------------------|-------------|-------------|--------- ---|
| 3 |a: pack<int, float, double>()      |  false      |  false      |  false      |
|   |b: pack<int, float, int>()         |             |             |             |
|---|-----------------------------------|-------------|-------------|--------- ---|
| 4 |a: pack<int, float, double>()      |  true       |  true       |  false      |
|   |b: pack<int, float, double>()      |             |             |             |
|---|-----------------------------------|-------------|-------------|--------- ---|
| 5 |a: pack<int, float, double>()      |  true       |  false      |  false      |
|   |b: pack<int>()                     |             |             |             |
|---|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The last two cases (4 and 5) are in question: are my expectation for the *more specialized template* wrong? and if so, who is right in case 4, clang or g++? (note that the code compiles without any error or warning on both, yet with different results).

Trying to answer that myself, I went several times through the "more specialized" rules in the spec [(14.5.6.2 Partial ordering of function templates)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf#page=354) and in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) -- it seems that the more specialized rule shall give the result I'm expecting (one may expect ambiguity error if not, but this is not the case either). So, what am I missing here?

---

Wait (1): please don't rush and bring the "[prefer not to overload templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)" of Herb Sutter and his [template methods quiz](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm). These are surely important, but the language still allows templates overloading! (It is indeed a strengthening point why you should prefer not to overload templates -- in some edge cases it may confuse two different compilers, or confuse the programmer. But the question is not whether to use it or not, it is: ***what is the right behavior if you do use it?***).

Wait (2): please don't rush to bring other possible solutions. There are for sure. Here are two: [one with inner struct](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52b7d44cc4482c24) and [another with inner static methods](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f93c81352d526dc6). Both are suitable solutions, both work as expected, yet the question regarding the above template overloading behavior still stays.

Comment: I suspect that the result is due to `PACK_A<Ts1..., Ts2...>`. Compiler should not be able to deduce the first parameter pack `Ts1...` as it is not at the end of the template. Therefore it should get empty and as such the overload should never be chosen. I don't know how come clang have chosen it in case 4.

Comment: As @W.F. says, the standard tell us that *"If the template argument list of P contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context."* (14.8.2.5/8), so g++ seems to be right and clang wrong.

Comment: confirming, changing the signature to `template <typename... Ts1, typename... Ts2 >
constexpr bool starts_with(pack<Ts1..., Ts2...>, pack<Ts1...>)` fixes it in gcc.

Comment: @RichardHodges you mean in clang?...

Comment: @W.F. no. it causes gcc to give the expected answer.

Comment: @RichardHodges in this case in my opinion both clang and gcc are wrong :)

Comment: @W.F. note that in two very similar cases (a sequence of two packs), g++ and clang succeed in deducing the first pack, resulting with the expected result (though, in one case with a warning in clang): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f93c81352d526dc6 and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52b7d44cc4482c24 -- so why these are ok and the above is not?

Comment: @AmirKirsh the `Ts...` from your examples are not deduced. They are known at the time the templated struct is specialized. This is the most crucial difference here. As the `Ts...` is not deduced there it can get placed there exactly as is.

Comment: @W.F. again confirmed. information answer updated. you should post an answer so that we can +1 it and delete mine.

Comment: What? You *should* overload function templates. You should not *specialise* them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Holt mentioned the standard is very strict when it comes to variadic template parameters deduction:

> 14.8.2.5/9
>
> If P has a form that contains T or i, then each argument Pi of the 
>   respective template argument list P is compared with the corresponding
>   argument Ai of the corresponding template argument list of A. **If the
>   template argument list of P contains a pack expansion that is not the
>   last template argument, the entire template argument list is a
>   non-deduced context.** If Pi is a pack expansion, then the pattern of Pi
>   is compared with each remaining argument in the template argument list
>   of A. Each comparison deduces template arguments for subsequent
>   positions in the template parameter packs expanded by Pi.

This as interpreted by T.C. would mean that `Ts1...` can be deduced from the second argument but it leaves no room to `Ts2...` deduction. As such apparently clang would be the right here and gcc would be wrong... The overload should be therefor chosen **only if** the second parameter would contain exactly the same template parameters e.g:

```
starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int, float, double>())
```

Still example 5. does not fulfil this requirement and does not allow compiler to chose the overload.

Comment: `PACK_A<Ts1..., Ts2...>` is a non-deduced context, but that doesn't mean that `Ts1...` is deduced as empty. It means it is not deduced from the first argument, but it can be deduced from the second argument. `Ts2...`, OTOH, is not deduced at all and is thus deduced to be empty.

Comment: @T.C. so `starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int, float, double>())` -> `true` is actually expected behaviour?

Comment: Sort of. It breaks http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#11, but nobody actually diagnoses that.

Comment: @T.C. 14.8.2.5/9 treat `PACK_A` as "the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context" - fair enough. But, none-deduced context can be deduced by another deduced context. So let's follow to 14.1/11: "A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed
by another template parameter **unless that template parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list
of the function**..." -- I believe we fall in the case of "parameter can be deduced from the parameter-type-list" (`PACK_B`) -- which means cases 4 and 5 can be deduced and shall work as expected (true, true)!

Comment: @T.C. Well, I think I found the rule in the spec... 14.8.2.1/1: "When a function parameter pack appears in a non-deduced context ..., **the type of that parameter pack is never deduced**." But then, clang is wrong and g++ is right in the initial scenario, and both are wrong in Richard Hodges scenario. A none deduced context shall fail this template (SFINAE) resulting with the 'false' result. Isn't it?

Comment: `Ts1` is a template parameter pack, not a function parameter pack. A function parameter pack is the `p` in `template<class... Ts> void f(Ts... p);`.

Answer (score 2):

information only: not an answer. This is a response to a question in the comments:

on gcc5.3 making the following small change induces it to produce the expected results, or at least the same results as clang.

```
rhodges@dingbat:~$ cat nod.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class... Ts>
struct pack { };

template <class a, class b>
constexpr bool starts_with(a, b) {
    return false;
}

template <typename... Ts1, typename... Ts2 >
constexpr bool starts_with(pack<Ts1..., Ts2...>, pack<Ts1...>) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
   std::cout << std::boolalpha;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<float, int, double>()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int, float, double, int>()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int, float, int>()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int, float, double>()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int>()) << std::endl;
}


rhodges@dingbat:~$ g++ -std=c++14 nod.cpp && ./a.out
false
false
false
true
false
rhodges@dingbat:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

rhodges@dingbat:~$
```

and for the record, modifying the program to evaluate all packs in deduced contexts brings success on both platforms:

```
rhodges@dingbat:~$ cat nod.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class... Ts>
struct pack { };

template <class a, class b>
constexpr bool starts_with_impl(a, b) {
    return false;
}

template<typename...LRest>
constexpr bool starts_with_impl(pack<LRest...>, pack<>)
{
    return true;
}

template<typename First, typename...LRest, typename...RRest>
constexpr bool starts_with_impl(pack<First, LRest...>, pack<First, RRest...>)
{
    return starts_with_impl(pack<LRest...>(), pack<RRest...>());
}

template <typename... Ts1, typename... Ts2 >
constexpr bool starts_with(pack<Ts2...> p1, pack<Ts1...> p2) {
    return starts_with_impl(p1, p2);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<float, int, double>()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int, float, double, int>()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int, float, int>()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int, float, double>()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << starts_with(pack<int, float, double>(), pack<int>()) << std::endl;
}


rhodges@dingbat:~$ g++ -std=c++14 nod.cpp && ./a.out
false
false
false
true
true
```

Credit to W.F. for guiding me in this direction.